# Revision control for windows, besides Git

Tags: version-control

What revision control do you use that works best for windows besides Git and you see staying around for the next generation of programmers.

Comment: Why don't you like git?  I understand it is pretty good.

Comment: Which VCS _doesn't_ work on Windows?

Comment: I use git on mac and I'm doing some android development on windows 7 and want to branch out, learn some other methods

Comment: I would want a source control system that is transparent, one that I don't have to think about much while I am coding.  One that is *uninteresting.*

Comment: "staying around for the next generation of programmers"? Man, that's quite a demand. Chances are for any given software to die long before a generation passes. Actually no: there are few people out there that write software that lasts across generations, and Linus Torvalds is one of them.

Comment: @Robert try RCS. It's uninteresting alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are **version control on windows beside GIT** in order of popularity in my review*

1. CVS**
2. SVN**
3. Mercurial**
4. Bazaar
5. LibreSource
6. Monotone

** are much better in my opinion

**Some links that must see before**

- [7 Version Control Systems Reviewed](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/18/the-top-7-open-source-version-control-systems/)
- [Comparison of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software)

Comment: I'd love to see Linus comment on this post, to be told that (especially CVS) is better than Git!

Comment: Doesnt mean CVS is better then GIT rather CVS is better beside GIT

Comment: JapanPro is correct, the title clearly states besides git

Answer (score 3):

Subversion.

For Windows, you can use [Visual SVN Server](http://visualsvn.com/server/). The basic version is free. Eliminates the need for setting up Apache/SVN Daemon type of setup.

Answer (score 0):

the obvious answer would be [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)

Comment: because it is by far the most popular of the new generation of source control systems after git.

Comment: ... and it has pretty good Windows support